# Return Promise and await are the exact same?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Considering the following 2 functions: one return promise object, one using await. Are they exact behavior the same under the hood?

```
async function f1 (event) {
  const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fetch('https://google.com')
      .then(p=>p.status)
    });
  return promise
}

async function f2 (event) {
  const res = await fetch('https://google.com');
  return res.status;
}
```

I believe I can also call like:

```
var r1 = await f1(url);
var r2 = await f2(url);
```

Question here: 
1. are the 2 callings correct?
2. f1 and f2 under the hook, are they exact same behaviour and usage?

Comment: I believe it would be `reject(e)`

Comment: @Intervalia `behaviour` is a valid word.

Comment: For function f1, you don't really need async because you already return a promise.

Comment: Yes , their output and functionality will be same

Answer (score 1):

If `http.get` returns a promise you can simplify the promise example to make it look like the `await` example. To answer your question simply, they do the same thing with different syntax.

```js
async function f1 (event) {
  return https
    .get(url)
    .then(res => res.statusCode);
}

async function f2 (event) {
  const res = await https.get(url);
  return res.statusCode;
}
```